# Best option to duplicate a rails app hosted on heroku and associated to a github repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, github, heroku-postgres

I have a rails web app named `first-app` (rails version: `4.1.7`).
This app is hosted on heroku and linked to a github repo (also named `first-app`).

For testing purposes, I want to create another rails app named `second-app` which should be identical (at the beginning) to `first-app`.

The 2 apps have to coexist separately: 2 different heroku dynos, 2 different postgre databases,  2 different github remotes.

*I have no idea which is the best option:*

1/ **From github to local**: clone the `first-app`repo on github to a new github repo named `second-app, then pull the`second-app`repo locally (with a`git pull`)

2/ **From local to github**: copy locally the `first-app` folder and paste it to a new folder named `second-app`  (I guess with a `$ cp -R first-app second-app` command), then create a new github remote from the `second-app` folder.

Has anyone any guidance on how to proceed ?

Plus, I guess that in every case I would have to manually change files to rename properly the `second-app`name, as well as setting up a new postgre database and dump it with the heroku `first-app` db.

Does it sound correct ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Definitely option 1.  That is kind of the point of a repository - you should be able to do things like clone projects easily.  And, yes, you would need to manually make the changes you describe.

Comment: Why does it need to have 2 separate github remote? Can't you create a staging branch for staging development?

Comment: @forthowin possibly but it sounds like this is a totally separate project so shouldn't it have a separate repository?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I would go with option one as suggested. Yes, I need two different repos and two different remotes as the two projects will evolve independently.